# AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'filter' - in Flask and Sqalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, select, insert, and_, update, delete
load_dotenv()

engine = create_engine(os.getenv('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'))
connection = engine.connect()
metadata = MetaData()

Inventory = Table('inventory', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine, extend_existing=True)   

@inventory.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def viewAll():
    query = select([Inventory]).filter(Inventory.id >=3)
    ResultProxy = connection.execute(query)
    ResultSet = ResultProxy.fetchall()
    res = []
    for rs in ResultSet:
        res.append(list_to_json(rs))
    return dict(enumerate(res))
```

I'm trying to run this code by adding a filter query. It shows an error saying AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'filter'.

The code runs fine without the filter query. So, Needed help to understand how to add a filter query to this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options to fix this error

1. Execute raw query (since you are using `connection.execute(query)`), e.g.:

```
def viewAll():
  query = 'SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE id >= 3'
  ResultProxy = connection.execute(query)
  ResultSet = ResultProxy.fetchall()
```

2. Use `session.query`, something like this:

```
def viewAll():
  ResultSet = self.session.query(Inventory).filter(Inventory.id >=3).all()
```

Comment: yes, I decided to use raw query for the filters now. 
At least there's enough freedom for me to manipulate the query like a string and fit it as per the requirements of the mutiple filters.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `skip` with `offset` (ie: `select([Inventory]).offset(3)`)